# Autohotkey, how to dectect key release when that key is used as a prefix

Tags: autohotkey

I have a concise question with the script below:

```
global Eme_Fn_idle := true

F1 UP:: 
    MsgBox, F1_up ; ★I wish to see this after pressing and releaseing F1+F9
    Eme_Fn_idle = true
return

F1 & F9::
    if (Eme_Fn_idle) {
        Eme_Fn_idle = false
        Eme_ClickOnDocTab(0, 0, 18)
    }
    else {
        Send ^!. ; switch to Right Document
    }
return
```

I can only see **F1_up** when I press and release <kbd>F1</kbd> alone. BUT, When I **press F1, press F9, release F9,  release F1** , I cannot see **F1_up** . How to see it any way?

Autohotkey 1.1.13.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this behavior either.  Obviously the F1 UP is being blocked by the program as shown in the key history (second to last line below has an s meaning it is suppressed or blocked):

```
h=Hook Hotkey, s=Suppressed (blocked)

70  03B s   d   0.89    F1              temp.ahk
70  03B h   u   0.17    F1              
0D  01C     d   0.31    Enter           temp.ahk
0D  01C     u   0.17    Enter           temp.ahk
70  03B s   d   1.36    F1              
78  043 h   d   0.17    F9              
78  043 s   u   0.16    F9              
70  03B s   u   0.45    F1              
26  148     d   0.95    Up
```

You could possibly add an `F1 & F9 UP::` but that will catch an OR condition of either F1 or F9 being released, so in a 4-stroke press (F1 Down, F9 Down, F9 Up, F1 Up), it would fire on the F9 Up, not the F1 Up.

One possible solution would be to make your own routine to detect the state of the keys and then independently call your code.  Probably related to the first issue, but the GetKeyState doesn't seem to work if you add the actual `F1::` call or `F1 & F9::` call, so try testing this standalone to see if it works right before integrating it with anything else.

```
waitingForF1Up := false
CheckF1Up:
    Loop
    {
        F1 := GetKeyState("F1", "P")
        F9 := GetKeyState("F9", "P")

        tooltip % F1 ", " F9

        if F1 and F9 and not waitingForF1Up
        {
            SetTimer, F1andF9, -1
            waitingForF1up := True
        }
        else if not F1 and waitingForF1up
        {
            SetTimer, F1up, -1
            waitingForF1up := False
        }

        sleep 10

    }

return

F1up:
    tooltip F1 up executed
    sleep 1000
    tooltip
return

F1andF9:
    tooltip F1 and F9 executed
    sleep 1000
    tooltip
return
```